# Comparar dois atributos datas na base dados com duas TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datetime, validação

Como posso comparar um intervalo de duas datas?

```
data_Inicio date
data_Fim date

textbox_inicio
textbox_fim
```

Poderei fazer isso logo do lado do ASP.NET sendo que o objetivo é que a minha data de início nunca seja inferior a minha data de fim e a minha data de fim nunca seja inferior a minha data de início.

Comment: Coloque como está seu código até agora

Comment: Qual é a Base de Dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considere usar um [componente próprio para datas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8). Dito isto vou tentar dar uma solução ao que parece ser o que precisa:

```
DateTime dataInicio;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(textbox_inicio.Text, out dataInicio)) {
    lblErro.Text =  "Formato da data inicial é inválido";
    lblErro.Visible = true;
    return;
}
DateTime dataFim;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(textbox_fim.Text, out dataFim)) {
    lblErro.Text =  "Formato da data final é inválido";
    lblErro.Visible = true;
    return;
}

if (DateTime.Compare(dataInicio.Date > dataFinal.Date) {
    lblErro.Text = "Data inicial não pode ser superior à data final";
    lblErro.Visible = true;
} else {
    lblErro.Text = "";
    lblErro.Visible = false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/TryParse.cs).

Isto é só uma base, dá para fazer melhor que isto e provavelmente será precisa adaptar ao que você precisa já que você não postou seu código.